# IBM WebSphere Update

Tags: websphere

I am trying to upgrade the current IBM WebSphere application to version 19.0.04 or interim fix PH06340. When I go to update the repositories the URL is not connected I believe the firewall is blocking it. how do I get the repositories to connect so that I can perform this upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the downloadable IBM Installation Manager repositories that will be linked from each fixpacks download page. For example 19.0.0.4's download page is https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/19004-websphere-application-server-liberty-19004#LibertyIM

You point IIM at those zips instead of URLs.

Comment: so i tried to point it to the zip files ut i got this error

Comment: CRIMA1071E JDK cannot be installed

Comment: Basically what is happening is that the IIM is still pointing to the old repositories even when I remove them and when i go to the IBM website to download the appropriate .zip file there's is an error and i cant download the files. So i am not sure what the issue is I need some guidance here.

Comment: Sounds like you need support from IBM, not programming Q&A here.

Comment: I have reached out to them but I may have to call them